# @RequestParam при использовании в регистрации выдает ошибку при пустых значениях

Tags: java, spring, валидация

**Шаблон**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>StartUp: Registration</title>

    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="modal-dialog">
    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="userForm" class="loginmodal-container">
    <h1>Create Your Account</h1><br>

    <spring:bind path="login">
    <div class="${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:errors path="login"></form:errors>
        <form:input type="text" path="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Login"
                    autofocus="true"></form:input>

    </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="password">
    <div class="${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:errors path="password"></form:errors>
        <form:input type="password" path="password" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Password"></form:input>
    </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="confirmPassword">
    <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:errors path="confirmPassword"></form:errors>
        <form:input type="password" path="confirmPassword" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Confirm your password"></form:input>
    </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="firstName">
    <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:errors path="firstName"></form:errors>
        <form:input type="text" path="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"
                    autofocus="true"></form:input>
    </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="lastName">
    <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:errors path="lastName"></form:errors>
        <form:input type="text" path="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"
                    autofocus="true"></form:input>
    </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="email">
    <div class="${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:errors path="email"></form:errors>
        <form:input type="text" path="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"
                    autofocus="true"></form:input>
    </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="phoneNumber">
    <div class="${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:input type="text" path="phoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number"
                    autofocus="true"></form:input>
    </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="country">
    <div class="${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:input type="text" path="country" class="form-control" placeholder="Country"
                    autofocus="true"></form:input>
    </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="city">
    <div class="${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:input type="text" path="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City"
                    autofocus="true"></form:input>
    </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <div class="btn-group form-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="radio" name="roleId" value="4" id="option1" checked> Founder
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="roleId" value="2" id="option2"> Investor
        </label>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <input onclick="location.href='home'" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" value="Cancel"/>
    </form:form>
    <bdiv>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Контроллер**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String registration(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new UserDB());

    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserDB userForm, @RequestParam(name = "roleId") long id, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    userForm.getRoles().add(roleRepository.getOne(id));

    userService.save(userForm);
    securityService.autoLogin(userForm.getLogin(), userForm.getConfirmPassword());
    return "redirect:/allstartups";
}
```

Ошибка происходит после не заполнения юзером полей. То есть по хорошему должно просто над полями выдать ошибки о необходимости заполнить поля, а из-за использования @RequestParam вылетает 400 ошибка.

Вот код валидации.

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return UserDB.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        UserDB user = (UserDB) o;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "login", "Required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstName", "Required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "lastName", "Required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "email", "Required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "Required");


        if (user.getLogin().length() < 6 || user.getLogin().length() > 32) {
            errors.rejectValue("login", "Size.userForm.login");
        }

        if (userService.findByLogin(user.getLogin()) != null) {
            errors.rejectValue("login", "Duplicate.userForm.login");
        }

        if (user.getPassword().length() < 8 || user.getPassword().length() > 32) {
            errors.rejectValue("password", "Size.userForm.password");
        }

        if (!user.getConfirmPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {
            errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword", "Different.userForm.password");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю, почему вы `roleId` так отделили от остальных параметров, но если именно так вам и надо, то попробуйте объявить его необязательным

```
@RequestParam(name = "roleId", required = false) Optional<Long> id
```

И проверять наличие в коде контроллера

```
if (!id.isPresent()) {
    // Какие-то действия
}
```